# how to show many image from URL in UIscrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I want create one page that has 3 horizontal (right to left) Scroll in top & middle & down page.

in each scrollview there are many image like this :

```
----------------------------------------
| -------    --------     --------     |
| |     |    |      |     |      |     |   Outside the box is scroller!!!
| |     |    |      |     |      |     |
| -------    --------     --------     |
----------------------------------------
```

in any page of scroll exist 3 image .

I want when change page of scroll images that exist this page changing!!! (like Scroll in IMDB application)

I can create Scroll and I can read many images from URL but I can not connect these!!! :(

please tell me about.

Comment: Can you not use `UICollectionView`?

Comment: I dont want to use UIColletion. I want make scroll (right to left) that show many image when touch right to left!!

Comment: I am pretty sure you can scroll right to left using a `UICollectioView`. What you are talking about doing is the reason why `UICollectionView` exists.

Comment: my friend I want create own application for ios 5 but I can not use UICollection. also I dont know about UICollection!!!

Comment: 1) Its called `UICollectionView` not `UICollection` 2) That is the sort of information you need to provide so we don't give you incorrect information. Your code needs to be dependent on `iOS` 3) Even though you don't want to use it learn about it http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Check [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) brilliant lib for doing stuff like that. It includes a lot of examples and compatible with iOS5.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

A.  Create a `UIView` to hold 3 `UImageViews` to contain the 3 images.

B.  Add the `UIView` as the `contentView` of the `UISrollView`.

C.  Use a combination of `UIPageControl` and `UIScrollView`.

Comment: @ma2012 We're not here to do it for you, we're here to help. Now if you don't know how to create a `UIView` with 3 `UIImageViews` on it then add that `UIView` to a `UIScrollView` then you should be doing some basic tutorials. Please go learn the basics then come back.